# Angular 2 Universal with Bootstrap 3 loads as desktop on Android phone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, angular

I had a responsive site built using Angular 2 which sized correctly on mobile devices. In order to gain SEO advantages, I switched to a starter project which used Angular Universal. I then moved all of my existing code across to the new project. Prior to adding Universal, the site displayed correctly on an Android device (by correctly, I mean the viewport size was small).

The site still looks as expected when loaded in Chrome on a desktop. If the size of the browser is reduced, it looks like I would expect it to on a mobile. For example,

[image: Chrome with browser minimised]

However, when I load the same site on my Android device, the site shows as I would expect on a larger screen which is a horrible mobile experience:

[image: Android screenshot]

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to isolate which code is causing the issue to include in this question, but with guidance, I will update this question. The domain is http://podroot.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the issue..
Following **meta tags** are missing(recommended by bootstrap 3)

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

you can follow [bootstrap: getting strated](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

after putting these tags, responsiveness is working as expected.
Here is a screenshot(from chrome device simulator) after modification.

[image]